# Java - Trying to understand Threading and new Thread(this).start();

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm very new to Thread. I'm trying to understand how to apply the usage of threading by making a simple program. It doesn't seem to be working. The program just ask for two inputs and terminate right away after assigning value to those two variables. Moreover, it throws `NullPointerException` if the `threadNum` variable is more than `1` Could you please explain the proper way to do this?
Also, I'm confused about constructing and starting a thread with `new Thread(this).start();`

```
package helloworld;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class HelloWorld implements Runnable {

private int threadNum;
private int taskNum;
private int loopNum;

public HelloWorld(int threadNum, int taskNum){
    this.taskNum = taskNum;
    this.threadNum = threadNum;

    int loop = taskNum / threadNum;
    this.loopNum = loop;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Task Num = ");
    int taskNum = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Thread Num = ");
    int threadNum = sc.nextInt();

    HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld(threadNum, taskNum);
    hello.activate();

}


public void activate(){
    Thread[] a = new Thread[this.threadNum];
    int count = 0;

    for(Thread x : a){
        x = new Thread(this);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 1 ; i++){

        while(count < loopNum){
            a[i].start();
            count++;
        }
        count = 0;

        while(count < taskNum - ((threadNum - 1) * loopNum)){
            a[a.length - 1].start();
            count ++;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println("Processing....");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Done !!");
}
```

}

Comment: Your foreach loop isn’t modifying the array.

Comment: You could debug your program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HelloWorld implements Runnable` means `new Thread(this)` is passing a `Runnable` to the constructor of `Thread`. You aren't actually filling `a` in your current code. You can do that like

```
Thread[] a = new Thread[this.threadNum];
for(int i = 0; i < this.threadNum; i++){
    a[i] = new Thread(this);
}
// Now `a` is filled with threads.
int count = 0;
```

Comment: The problem is nothing to do with threading, its just how to set an array in a loop.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I assumed OP was asking two questions; the first about the empty array and the second about the meaning of `new Thread(this)`... perhaps I parsed it incorrectly.

Comment: Good point. When people say `x` is confusing, it's not always clear to me what they find confusing about it. For me the confusing part might be how `start()` calls `run()` in a new thread. ;)